# Using Pylint with Django

Tags: python, django, static-analysis, pylint

I would very much like to integrate [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) into the build process for
my python projects, but I have run into one show-stopper:  One of the
error types that I find extremely useful--:`E1101: *%s %r has no %r
member*`--constantly reports errors when using common django fields,
for example:

```
E1101:125:get_user_tags: Class 'Tag' has no 'objects' member
```

which is caused by this code:

```
def get_user_tags(username):
   """
   Gets all the tags that username has used.

   Returns a query set.
   """
   return Tag.objects.filter(  ## This line triggers the error.
       tagownership__users__username__exact=username).distinct()

# Here is the Tag class, models.Model is provided by Django:
class Tag(models.Model):
   """
   Model for user-defined strings that help categorize Events on
   on a per-user basis.
   """
   name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, unique=True)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

How can I tune Pylint to properly take fields such as objects into account?  (I've also looked into the Django source, and I have been unable to find the implementation of `objects`, so I suspect it is not "just" a class field.  On the other hand, I'm fairly new to python, so I may very well have overlooked something.)

**Edit:** The only way I've found to tell pylint to not warn about these warnings is by blocking all errors of the type (E1101) which is not an acceptable solution, since that is (in my opinion) an extremely useful error.  If there is another way, without augmenting the pylint source, please point me to specifics :)

See [here](http://creswick.github.io/blog/2008/09/05/wrestling-python/) for a summary of the problems I've had with `pychecker` and `pyflakes` -- they've proven to be far to unstable for general use.  (In pychecker's case, the crashes originated in the pychecker code -- not source it was loading/invoking.)

Comment: see @talweiss's post for an up-to-date answer!

Comment: Found good solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31000713/78234

Comment: Can you please accept @talweiss 's answer? It's the most up-to-date and correct solution.

Answer (score 172):

Do not disable or weaken Pylint functionality by adding `ignores` or `generated-members`.
Use an actively developed Pylint plugin that **understands** Django.
[This Pylint plugin for Django](https://github.com/landscapeio/pylint-django) works quite well:

```
pip install pylint-django
```

and when running pylint add the following flag to the command:

```
--load-plugins pylint_django
```

Detailed blog post [here](https://blog.landscape.io/using-pylint-on-django-projects-with-pylint-django.html).

Comment: The link to the blog post is dead (so soon). Here are some archived links from the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20141008054046/http://blog.landscape.io/using-pylint-on-django-projects-with-pylint-django.html) and from [archive.is](http://archive.is/Lb9f0)

Comment: To make it work with Sublime Text's SublimeLinter plugin, I had to add `--load-plugins=pylint_django` to linters/pylint/args setting. Note the '=' sign, it didn't work without it.

Comment: it does not work. I get this error: E:  8, 0: No name 'models' in module 'django.db' (no-name-in-module)

Comment: @max What's your full command line? Versions of Django and pylint? Full output of the pylint run?

Comment: django 1.8 pylint==1.4.3
pylint-django==0.7.1
I dont think it's appropriate to put the stacktrace here...

Comment: Using django 1.9, pylint 1.5.2, and pylint-django 0.7.1, pylint_django plugin did not show `models.Manager.get` as a valid method.

Comment: Can you make an example how I would use it on a Django project? pylint --load-plugins pylint_django (how do I address my Django projekt here?)

Comment: You can also add this in your pylintrc: ```[MASTER]


load-plugins=pylint_django```

Comment: In vs code it dose not work for me until I Put in the following in the user settings:
`{"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
     "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
],}`
[tieuminh2510's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343542/5697765)

Comment: @azmeuk Thank you! I could not figure out the section header! Why is it MASTER? Where is this documented? How would I find out next time what the .pylintrc format and sections should look like?

Comment: Honestly, I cannot remember where I found this :(

Answer (score 64):

I use the following: `pylint --generated-members=objects`

Comment: [man pylint(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pylint.1.html) under TYPECHECK `--generated-members=<members names>` List of  members which are set dynamically and missed by pylint inference system, and so shouldn't trigger E0201 _and E1101_ when  accessed. [current: REQUEST,acl_users,aq_parent]

Comment: I add this in PyDev in eclipse under [preferences in the PyDev/PyLint section](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_pylint.html).

Comment: Using generated-members just hides these errors from you, there still can be errors when trying to access objects field on the wrong object. Use pylint-django plugin instead.

Comment: This is the wrong way to fix Pylint - by disabling some of its functionality. All you need to do is install a Pylint plugin that **understands** Django. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31000713/78234

Answer (score 40):

If you use Visual Studio Code do this:

`pip install pylint-django`

And add to VSC config:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
],
```

Comment: Best response by far :D

Answer (score 31):

My ~/.pylintrc contains

```
[TYPECHECK]
generated-members=REQUEST,acl_users,aq_parent,objects,_meta,id
```

the last two are specifically for Django.

Note that there is a [bug in PyLint 0.21.1](http://www.logilab.org/ticket/28796) which needs patching to make this work.

Edit:  After messing around with this a little more, I decided to hack PyLint just a tiny bit to allow me to expand the above into:

```
[TYPECHECK]
generated-members=REQUEST,acl_users,aq_parent,objects,_meta,id,[a-zA-Z]+_set
```

I simply added:

```
    import re
    for pattern in self.config.generated_members:
        if re.match(pattern, node.attrname):
            return
```

after the fix mentioned in the bug report (i.e., at line 129).

Happy days!

Comment: You should submit your patch to pylint back to the maintainers.

Comment: actually they've included this patch in 0.24, but they've started using the `shlex` package, and broken something else now.  I had to add `gen.wordchars += "[]-+"` at line 135 to get it to work...

Comment: Using generated-members just hides these errors from you, there still can be errors when trying to access 'objects' field on the wrong object. Use pylint-django plugin instead.

Comment: This is the wrong way to fix Pylint - by disabling some of its functionality. All you need to do is install a Pylint plugin that **understands** Django. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31000713/78234

Comment: @TalWeiss -- in fairness, this answer is three years older than `pylint-django`, so the downvote is a bit harsh...

Answer (score 19):

django-lint is a nice tool which wraps pylint with django specific settings : http://chris-lamb.co.uk/projects/django-lint/

github project: https://github.com/lamby/django-lint

Comment: I like the idea of a Django-specific pylint, but it seems a big buggy last time I tried it.

Comment: Also it's not available via PyPI and the website doesn't seem to give enough info like: What's the current version?

Comment: I like the concept, but this implementation is only half-baked, and breaks on any moderately sized codebase. It has a long way to go before it's actual useful.

Comment: `django-lint`? that's quite interesting. I'll look into it

Comment: @gurney alex, Link is dead.

Comment: Looks like pylint-django is more active now, that should be the advised solution.

Comment: Link is broken and Github repo has not been touched in 3 years. For an active solution and a Pylint plugin that **understands** Django. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31000713/78234

Answer (score 16):

Because of how pylint works (it examines the source itself, without letting Python actually execute it) it's very hard for pylint to figure out how metaclasses and complex baseclasses actually affect a class and its instances. The 'pychecker' tool is a bit better in this regard, because it *does* actually let Python execute the code; it imports the modules and examines the resulting objects. However, that approach has other problems, because it does actually let Python execute the code :-)

You could extend pylint to teach it about the magic Django uses, or to make it understand metaclasses or complex baseclasses better, or to just ignore such cases after detecting one or more features it doesn't quite understand. I don't think it would be particularly easy. You can also just tell pylint to not warn about these things, through special comments in the source, command-line options or a .pylintrc file.

Comment: It is not easy to teach Pylint about Django, but it has been done: All you need to do is install a Pylint plugin that **understands** Django. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31000713/78234

Comment: Well I installed it but it still compains about thins like QuerySet has no remove...

Answer (score 7):

I resigned from using pylint/pychecker in favor of using pyflakes with Django code - it just tries to import module and reports any problem it finds, like unused imports or uninitialized local names.

Comment: interesting -- I'll give pyflakes another look.

Comment: PyChecker catches much less than pylint. http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/CompletelyDifferent-2008-03-linters/index.html

Comment: No need to give up on Pylint - All you need to do is install a Pylint plugin that **understands** Django. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31000713/78234

Answer (score 7):

This is not a solution, but you can add `objects = models.Manager()` to your Django models without changing any behavior.

I myself only use pyflakes, primarily due to some dumb defaults in pylint and laziness on my part (not wanting to look up how to change the defaults).

Comment: Ah... thanks for the tip.  I may try just adding that to Model.models in the local copy of the django source, and see if that does it.

Comment: I think this a great solution because it doesn't compromise on warnings.

Comment: This is a *bad* solution. Repeating yourself and replacing something that it is feasible will change later (thus introducing a QA problem), just to fix an incomplete QA tool?

Comment: I wouldn't call this a bad solution: explicit is better than implicit. Perhaps `objects` shouldn't be magically added anyway.

Comment: I think that this is the wrong way to fix Pylint - by patching Django in a sense. All you need to do is install a Pylint plugin that **understands** Django. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31000713/78234

Answer (score 5):

Try running pylint with

```
pylint --ignored-classes=Tags
```

If that works, add all the other Django classes - possibly using a script, in say, python :P

The documentation for `--ignore-classes` is:

> `--ignored-classes=<members names>`
>   List of classes names for which member
>   attributes should not be checked
>   (useful for classes with attributes
>   dynamicaly set). [current: %default]

I should add this is not a particular elegant solution in my view, but it should work.

Comment: It only works if I never make any errors in those classes ;).  I want to avoid ignoring code if at all possible -- I think it is a very bad idea to have different parts of the codebase analyzed an different degrees of scrutiny. I will forget which is which, and make false assumptions when debugging

Comment: This is the wrong way to fix Pylint - by disabling some of its functionality. All you need to do is install a Pylint plugin that **understands** Django. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31000713/78234

Answer (score 4):

For `neovim & vim8` use `w0rp's ale` plugin.  If you have installed everything correctly including `w0rp's ale`, `pylint` & `pylint-django`. In your `vimrc` add the following line & have fun developing web apps using django.
Thanks.

```
let g:ale_python_pylint_options = '--load-plugins pylint_django'
```

Comment: did work perfect for me, on bought vim and neovim, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The solution proposed in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509599/can-an-api-tell-pylint-not-to-complain-in-the-client-code) it to simply add **get_attr** to your Tag class. Ugly, but works.

Answer (score 1):

So far I have found no real solution to that but work around:

- In our company we require a pylint
  score > 8. This allows coding
  practices pylint doesn't understand
  while ensuring that the code isn't
  too "unusual". So far we havn't seen
  any instance where E1101 kept us
  from reaching a score of 8 or
  higher.
- Our 'make check' targets
  filter out "for has no 'objects'
  member" messages to remove most of
  the distraction caused by pylint not
  understanding Django.

Answer (score 0):

For heroku users, you can also use [Tal Weiss's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31000713/527489) using the following syntax to run pylint with the pylint-django plugin (replace `timekeeping` with your app/package):

```
# run on the entire timekeeping app/package
heroku local:run pylint --load-plugins pylint_django timekeeping

# run on the module timekeeping/report.py
heroku local:run pylint --load-plugins pylint_django timekeeping/report.py

# With temporary command line disables
heroku local:run pylint --disable=invalid-name,missing-function-docstring --load-plugins pylint_django timekeeping/report.py
```

Note: I was unable to run without specifying project/package directories.

If you have issues with `E5110: Django was not configured.`, you can also invoke as follows to try to work around that (again, change `timekeeping` to your app/package):

```
heroku local:run python manage.py shell -c 'from pylint import lint; lint.Run(args=["--load-plugins", "pylint_django", "timekeeping"])'

# With temporary command line disables, specific module
heroku local:run python manage.py shell -c 'from pylint import lint; lint.Run(args=["--load-plugins", "pylint_django", "--disable=invalid-name,missing-function-docstring", "timekeeping/report.py"])'
```