# Class has no objects member

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
def index(request):
   latest_question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
   template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
   context = {'latest_question_list':latest_question_list}
   return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

The first line of that function gets an error on `Question.objects.all()`:

> E1101: Class 'Question' has no 'objects' member

I'm following the Django documentation tutorial and they have the same code up and running.

I have tried calling an instance.

```
Question = new Question()
and using MyModel.objects.all()
```

Also my `models.py` code for that class is this...

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published') 

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

To no avail I still have this error.

I have read about pylint and ran this...

```
pylint --load-plugins pylint_django
```

Which didn't help, even tho the github readme file says...

> Prevents warnings about Django-generated attributes such as
> Model.objects or Views.request.

I ran the command within my virtualenv, and yet nothing.

So any help would be great.

Comment: Use `pylint --generated-members=objects`

Comment: Sorry, ran it in my cmd and it didn't change a thing.

Comment: what is your python and django version?

Comment: verson python 3.6.0 and django 1.11.3

Comment: I'm assuming your models.py file has indents following the class and imports models at the top like in the tutorial?

Comment: yeah the formatting is fine. im just new to stackoverflow

Comment: Do you have any other thing named `Question` in your source code?

Comment: no i dont @rohan

Comment: have you made migartions properly? and can you post the whole view file?

Comment: just change this line and migrate and then run the view once, return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1) to return self.pub_date >= datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

Comment: @buuencrypted Please install pylint-django and restart your ide while check it. That will prevent that warning.

Comment: Judging by the fact you're willing to define an instance with the class name (`Question = new Question()`), I presume you've made the same mistake elsewhere, don't shadow class names with instances

Comment: For me what solved the issue was creating a `Manager` instance in the `models.py` file. Refer to [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/class/) for more info.

Answer (score 441):

Install `pylint-django` using `pip` as follows

```
pip install pylint-django
```

Then in Visual Studio Code goto: **User Settings** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or File > Preferences > Settings if available ) Put in the following (please note the curly braces which are required for custom user settings in VSC):

```
"pylint.args": ["load-plugins=pylint_django"],
```

Comment: where is  User Settings

Comment: Go to File->Preferences->Settings

or use "Ctrl + Comma"

Comment: Excellent! I'd also point out that you can put the plugin option in a `.pylintrc` file like so:

`load-plugins=pylint_django`

And that way it will be picked up by the CLI as well, so it would work in a continuous integration setting.

Comment: After doing so i am getting `[pylint] C0111:Missing module docstring` error

Comment: @VishnuSharma, add a comment after or before the module

Comment: I am getting new errors after applying this solution. Switching to the flask8 linter as suggested by another solution worked better for me.

Comment: More details in the official doc: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_commandline-arguments-and-configuration-files

Comment: I would suggest to check the link provided by @AntonDanilchenko, because the way the parameters are specified has changed for VS Code 1.40.0 and they way provided by this answer doesn't work anymore (as I just have tested). They way described by the link works.

Comment: How should PyCharm (Community Edition) users proceed to have pylint-django to work ?

Comment: does not seem to work with django 2.2 and python 3.6. the pylint_django does not seem to detect reverse OneToOne and I still get E1101 for those references.

Comment: add `{"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins=pylint_django"],}` to .vscode/settings.json after `pip install pylint-django`

Comment: my mac complains when I use pip directly and I have python3 installed so for the first step I did `python3 -m pip install pylint-django`.

Comment: @VishnuSharma by adding the configuration. **it disables the default values of Pylint**, so you should add default values manually. 
You can do so as followed: 
`{"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
"--load-plugins=pylint_django", 
"--disable=all", 
"--enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode" 
    ]}`
[for more info](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_commandline-arguments-and-configuration-files)

Comment: This doesn't work in the new version of VSC. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 170):

[@tieuminh2510's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343542/5305519) is perfect. But in newer versions of VSC you will not find the option to edit or paste that command in `User Settings`.

For newer versions, add the code in the following steps:

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> to open the the Command Palette.
2. Now in Command Palette type `Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings`.
3. Select `Python`.
4. Add these lines inside the first curly braces:

```
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
            "--load-plugins=pylint_django",
        ]
```

> Make sure that `pylint-django` is also installed.

Comment: don't forget to put a comma in the json file otherwise, it will not work correctly.

Comment: Also don't forget to `pip install pylint-django`. If the extension is not installed, this change to your settings seems to fail quietly, breaking all linting.

Comment: Thank you. You can find the same info in the official VS Code documentation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_commandline-arguments-and-configuration-files

Comment: It solved the earlier error. But, now a warning is coming. ```Missing module docstringpylint(missing-module-docstring)```. What can be done for this ?

Comment: This also has to be added 
 "--django-settings-module=trydjango.settings"

Answer (score 48):

Install Django pylint:

```
pip install pylint-django
```

ctrl+shift+p > Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings > Python

The settings.json available for python language should look like the below:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
    ],

    "[python]": {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 41):

I've tried all possible solutions offered but unluckly my vscode settings won't changed its linter path. So, I tride to explore vscode settings in **settings > User Settings > python**. Find **Linting: Pylint Path** and change it to "pylint_django". Don't forget to change the linter to "pylint_django" at **settings > User Settings > python configuration** from "pyLint" to "pylint_django".

[image: Linter Path Edit]

Comment: Worked for me on MacOS High Sierra and VSC 1.38, providing that previously I ran "pip install pylint-django" in my virtual environment.

Answer (score 32):

Heres the answer.
Gotten from my reddit post...
https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/6nq0bq/class_question_has_no_objects_member/

> That's not an error, it's just a warning from VSC. Django adds that
>   property dynamically to all model classes (it uses a lot of magic
>   under the hood), so the IDE doesn't know about it by looking at the
>   class declaration, so it warns you about a possible error (it's not).
>   objects is in fact a Manager instance that helps with querying the DB.
>   If you really want to get rid of that warning you could go to all your
>   models and add objects = models.Manager() Now, VSC will see the
>   objects declared and will not complain about it again.

Comment: `objects = models.Manager()` in the models class did it for me in VS Code. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

**UPDATE FOR VS CODE 1.40.0**

After doing:

```
$ pip install pylint-django
```

Follow this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_default-pylint-rules

Notice that the way to make `pylint` have into account `pylint-django` is by specifying:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"]
```

in the `settings.json` of VS Code.

But after that, you will notice a lot of new linting errors. Then, read what it said here:

> These arguments are passed whenever the `python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers` is set to `true` (the default). If you specify a value in `pylintArgs` or use a Pylint configuration file (see the next section), then **`pylintUseMinimalCheckers` is implicitly set to false**.

What I have done is creating a `.pylintrc` file as described in the link, and then, configured the following parameters inside the file (leaving the rest of the file untouched):

```
load-plugins=pylint_django

disable=all

enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode
```

Now `pylint` works as expected.

Comment: Instead of creating a separate .pylintrc file, you can get the same effect by doing this in your settings.json:

{
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django",
        "--disable=all",
        "--enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode"
    ]
}

Answer (score 14):

You can change the linter for Python extension for Visual Studio Code.

In VS open the Command Palette Ctrl+Shift+P and type in one of the following commands:

> Python: Select Linter

when you select a linter it will be installed. I tried flake8 and it seems issue resolved for me.

Comment: While this did work, I found flake8 really annoying as a linter.

Answer (score 11):

Just adding on to what @Mallory-Erik said: 
You can place `objects = models.Manager()` it in the modals:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Comment: That's the only solution which works for me with Django 3 and Python 3.8. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to update the user settings.json

On my mac it was stored in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
```

Within it, I set the following:

```
{
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint",
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"]
}
```

That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

Change your linter to - **flake8** and problem will go away.

Comment: I found this useful, clicked CMD + SHIFT + P and searched Python: Select Linter      and just select flake8!

Answer (score 4):

First install **pylint-django** using following command

```
$ pip install pylint-django
```

Then run the second command as follows:

```
$ pylint test_file.py --load-plugins pylint_django
```

**--load-plugins pylint_django is necessary for correctly review a code of django**

Answer (score 3):

If you use python 3

```
python3 -m pip install pylint-django
```

If python < 3

```
python -m pip install pylint-django==0.11.1
```

NOTE: Version 2.0, requires pylint >= 2.0 which doesn’t support Python 2 anymore! (https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/)

Answer (score 3):

First, Install `pylint-django` using `pip` as follows:

```
pip install pylint-django
```

Goto `settings.json` find and make sure `python linting enabled` is `true`
like this:

[image]

At the bottom write `"python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint_django"`like this:

[image]

OR,

Go to `Settings` and search for `python linting`

make sure `Python > Linting: Pylint Enabled` is checked

Under that `Python > Linting: Pylint Path` write `pylint_django`

Comment: thank you sir, this was driving me crazy, because i was trying everything that all the other answers were suggesting, but nothing worked for me until i found your answer and read that i needed to add the pylint django path to settings.json

"python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint_django",

Answer (score 2):

How about suppressing errors on each line specific to each error?

Something like this: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html

Error: [pylint] Class 'class_name' has no 'member_name' member
It can be suppressed on that line by:

```
  # pylint: disable=no-member
```

Comment: As brute-force as this solution is, it's the only way to preserve one's sanity. I'm getting those errors on dozens of different modules, I'm not going to change settings every time I see a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I installed PyLint but I was having the error `Missing module docstringpylint(missing-module-docstring)`. So I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54881400/11100735) with this config for pylint :

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=C0111", // missing docstring
    "--load-plugins=pylint_django,pylint_celery",
 ],
```

And now it works

Comment: Are you sure this answers the questions being asked?

Comment: I tried to install pylint as the first answer `pip install pylint-django` but after that I was having the `Missing module docstringpylint(missing-module-docstring)`.

So, I searched and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304116/enabling-pylint-django-plugin-in-vscode-pylint-stop-working/54881400#54881400) with a configuration for pylint that works for me. 

So, I think this complements the answers for this question. If I'm doing it wrong, excuse me, but I'm a newbie here.

Comment: I improved my answer. If it is not better, please point it out.

Answer (score 1):

By doing `Question = new Question()` (I assume the `new` is a typo) you are overwriting the Question model with an intance of `Question`. Like Sayse said in the comments: don't use the same name for your variable as the name of the model. So change it to something like `my_question = Question()`.

Comment: its something with my pc config of django and pytho, i recoded it on my macbook and it works just fine. Also i tried ur suggestion in my code and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happend when I use pylint_runner

So what I do is open .pylintrc file and add this

```
# List of members which are set dynamically and missed by pylint inference
# system, and so shouldn't trigger E1101 when accessed. Python regular
# expressions are accepted.
generated-members=objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add objects = None in your Questions table. That solved the error for me.