# Why does queryset=Post.objects.all() evaluate to Error when queryset is set to Post.objects.all()?

Tags: python, django

when I set `queryset=Post.objects.all()` the `Post` class shows the error

> "/d:/Programming/Python/Python_WorkPlace/New_django_project/posts/views.py",
>       **"message": "Class 'Post' has no 'objects' member"**

Why so and how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share your `Post`s model? Does it inherit from `Model`?

Comment: Or did you perhaps add an extra manager to the `Post`s model?

Comment: Is this just a warning from the IDE that can be ignored?

Comment: also, abstract models have no `objects` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your Post model,

```
class Post(models.Model):
    #rest of your code
    objects = models.Manager()
```

If you are not defining Manager instance, then 'objects' is added by default. In your case you are not getting objects by default. So you can add this manually.

Or if you are getting IDE warning only, in VS Code I guess, then install pylint, better described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135263/class-has-no-objects-member)

Refer [Official Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/class/#objects)