# How to fix "myClass has no objects member"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

After I added the method `post_detail` in the file ['~/blog/views.py'](https://github.com/tamercuba/my-first-blog/blob/master/blog/views.py) im getting the error `Class 'Post' has no 'objects' member` but before doing this the code was working so well.

I read a lot of stuff about Models on Django website but i cant find the error.

The django server is working fine, 0 errors.

I really cant understand why this error and why my application dont work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135263/class-has-no-objects-member

Comment: oh god, i really dont read that, so sorry. Works fine ty!

Answer (score 0):

Install pylint-django using pip as follows

```
pip install pylint-django
```

Then in VS Code follow these steps
Step 1: press CTR+SHIFT+P
Step 2:type in 'configure language specific settings' and select it
Step 3: type in 'python' and select it
Step 4: replace the content of you found there with the following snippet

```
{
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
],

"[python]": {

},

}
```

That's it!

Comment: Hi. The comments already pointed to an answer. Please do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. [See How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)