# myModel has no 'object' member / How to setup pylint-django

Tags: django, python-3.x

In my view I want to store in a variables every object from myModel but I have the Class 'myModel' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member) error

I have red that installing pylint-django as suggested by this similar topic : [Class has no objects member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135263/class-has-no-objects-member/53484813) 
but it didn't resolved my error then (in the same topic) I red that adding this

```
  "[python]": {
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
      "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
    ],
  },
```

To my settings.json would do the trick but I have the warning : Unknown Identifier. Use language identifiers and the error on myModel.objects is still here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after more reaserching I found that going to User settings > python : pylint path and replacing pylint by pylint_django worked !