# i got this error while fetching data from the models.py

Tags: django

```
def publicationlist(request):
    context = {'publication_list' : AddPublication.objects.all()}
    return render(request,"publication_list.html", context)
```

> Class 'AddPublication' has no 'objects' member

Comment: Can you share the `AddPublication` class/model?

Comment: class AddPublication(models.Model):
    addpublication = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class has no objects member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135263/class-has-no-objects-member)

Comment: no got the same error again

Comment: Can you share full error message? It really looks like pylint error that doesn't know about Django model manager method.