# Class.objects in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

So here is my view.py. In my models.py I have 2 models Question and a Choice the choice is connected to Question model. I am able to access the admin page.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.template import loader
from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})


def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)


def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

This is my model for my Django project.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

and here is the error I am getting this error in visual studio code in the problems page in the web when I run it I get the error Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
:

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
```

from . import views

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Here is my Index.html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
  {% for question in latest_question_list %}
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

and here is my detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
<ul>
  {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
  <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

> Class 'Question' has no 'objects' member

Comment: Are you sure there is no `Question` function/class/... in your `views.py` such that `Questions` thus refers to the wrong item?

Comment: Where are you getting that error? If it's from your code editor, then you can ignore it. If it appears when you run `manage.py runserver`, then please show the full `views.py` including the imports.

Comment: Okay so I am using visual studio code and in there I get a squiggly line saying "ss 'Question' has no 'objects' member"

I can run the server but I get a error like "Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
"

Comment: If you want to fix the warning from vscode, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135263/class-has-no-objects-member) might help. For help with the `ReverseMatchError`, you need to show your `urls.py` and the template where you use `{% url 'detail' ... %}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url name needs the app namespace, `polls`.

```
{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}
```

Comment: So it does work but I still have this error "Class 'Question' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member)
"

Comment: That's because you've redefined `Question` to be a non-Model class.

Comment: Okay, how can I fix it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't redefine it or import the Question model with an alias.

Comment: To fix the objects warning, see the question I linked to above