# Django 3: AttributeError: 'AdminSite' object has no attribute 'Register'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

AttributeError: 'AdminSite' object has no attribute 'Register'

when i go to make migrations and open my admin section to add so dummy info and image I receive the error.

```
admin.site.Register(Bet, BetAdmin)
```

What I have done so far is delete and hit return to see if it was indentation mistake on the class.

I also installed pylint to see more details on errors based on the one suggested answers.

[Class has no objects member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135263/class-has-no-objects-member)

```
pip install pylint-django
```

then I added to my setttings.json

```
   {
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "PowerShell ISE",
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\taylo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe",
    "json.schemas": [

    ],
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
    ],

    "[python]": {

    }

}
```

but it didn't seam to solve anything related to issue.

FYI: I did a bunch of searches and view on stack and but solutions seen where for spelling errors ased on the word being spelled incorrectly with q  like reqister instead of register is and was not spelled wrong.

the full terminal error

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\taylo\django\pybet_project> python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\taylo\django\pybet_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\taylo\django\pybet_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\taylo\django\pybet_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\taylo\django\pybet_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\taylo\django\pybet_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\taylo\django\pybet_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\taylo\django\pybet_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules     
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Users\taylo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\taylo\django\pybet_project\bets\admin.py", line 8, in <module>
    admin.site.Register(Bet, BetAdmin)
  File "C:\Users\taylo\django\pybet_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 225, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'AdminSite' object has no attribute 'Register'
(venv) PS C:\Users\taylo\django\pybet_project>
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Bet


class BetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = {'home_team', 'away_team', 'home_team_odds', 'draw_odds', 'away_team_odds'}

admin.site.Register(Bet, BetAdmin)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Bet(models.Model):
    home_team = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    home_team_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos')
    away_team = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    away_team_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos')
    home_team_odds = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    draw_odds = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    away_team_odds = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('new', views.new, name='new')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Bet

def index(request):
    bets = Bet.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'bets/index.html', {'bets: bets'})
```

Comment: It should be **`admin.site.register(Bet, BetAdmin)`** not `admin.site.Register(Bet, BetAdmin)`

Comment: awesome thanks works thank you got abunch of other errors but will try to sort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`admin.site.register()` - R must be lowercase

Comment: thanks this worked.