# Unable to view database on frontend in Django via Shell

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Hello wonderful people.

I am currently learning Django and trying to display the database which is created via **form** on **inventiory_view.html**

I am unable to do so via shell scripting.

I am able to display the objects via shell terminal but whenever I use the same command which is `Form1.objects.all` I am unable to display it on my desired **html** page.

I would really appreciate your help in this matter.

Thanks in advance

This is the **form1.html** where I am getting the data from the user.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

{% block title %} Title of Form1 {% endblock %}
  </head>
  {% block body %}
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Form1</h1>
    <form method="POST" action=" /form1/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Item name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name= "item" placeholder="laptop">
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Quantity </label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name= "quantity" placeholder="1,2,3">
          </div>     -->
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Quantity</label>
          <select class="form-control" input type="number" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name= "quantity">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Vendor name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name= "vendor" placeholder="Nokia">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Inward Number</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name= "inward" placeholder="2569">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" > Submit</button>
      </form>
      <a href="{% url 'export-csv' %}" class = "btn btn-secondary">Export CSV</a>
       {% endblock %}
     

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from form.models import Form1
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
import csv

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
  return render(request, 'index.html')
   # return HttpResponse("homepage")

def form1(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        item = request.POST.get('item')
        quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
        vendor = request.POST.get('vendor')
        inward = request.POST.get('inward')
        form1 = Form1(item = item, quantity = quantity , vendor=vendor , inward= inward)
        form1.save()

        send_mail(
    'Test Email from IT team',
    'We have received ' +  str(quantity) + ' quantity of ' + item + ' from ' + vendor + ' \n Inward Register Number'  + str(inward)  ,
    # 'Hello, IT team. Whenever an inventory will be added you will get the email sent to you or anyone who is concerned' ,
    'techdevio20@example.com',
    ['sam.atharkar@gmail.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
    return render(request, 'form1.html')
    # return HttpResponse("Form 1 ")


def export_csv(request):

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="inventory.csv"'

    writer= csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['item', 'inward', 'quantity', 'vendor name'])

    inventory = Form1.objects.all()
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Form1(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    inward = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from form import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name = 'home'),
    path('form1/',views.form1, name = 'form1'),
    path('form2/',views.form2, name = 'form2'),
    path('login/',views.login, name = 'login'),
    path('signup/',views.signup, name = 'signup'),
    path('search/',views.search, name = 'search'),
    path('inventory_view/',views.inventory_view, name = 'inventory_view'),
    
]
```

Comment: Have you look in the Django documentation, you have great tutorials to do exactly this type of thing. I suggest you to use the ModelForm builtin : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a seperate **view** to check all your objects like this:

```
def form1_entries(request):
    context = {}
    entries = Form1.objects.all()
    context['entries'] = entries
    return render(request, 'form1_entries.html', context)
```

Then in your **form1_entries.html** do this:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.item }} 
    {{ entry.quantity }}
    {{ entry.vendor }}
    {{ entry.inward }}
{% endfor %}
```

***Or*** just query the entries in the **view** where you have your **form**(form1) and pass them in the **context** of that **view**, then ofcourse you would have to add the **html** I included to your other template as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response @SLDem

Yes but on Form1.objects.all() it says 



-> Class 'Form1' has no 'objects' member pylint(no-member)

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343542/14535309

Comment: @SLMDem it worked :D
Thanks a lot you are a lifesaver