# Pylint Django model instance of 'str' has no member

Tags: django, python-3.x, pylint

I am using [pylint-django](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django) for my Django project and one of my models is as follows:

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        first_name = self.user.first_name
        last_name = self.user.last_name
        return f'{first_name} {last_name}'
```

Running pylint, I am getting the following warnings:

`events/models.py:61:21: E1101: Instance of 'str' has no 'first_name' member (no-member)`

From the readme of pylint-django I understand this is a known issue:

"If you reference foreign-key models by their name (as string) pylint-django may not be able to find the model and will report issues because it has no idea what the underlying type of this field is."

My question is: what should I do to deal with this? I prefer not to suppress all `C0111` warnings.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

PS: I am using pylint-django as answered on [Using Pylint with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31000713/7547749)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can supress a warning for a certain code *block*:

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        # pylint: disable=E1101
        first_name = self.user.first_name
        last_name = self.user.last_name
        return f'{first_name} {last_name}'
```

Here you will thus only disable `E1101` for that specific `__str__` method. If you want to re-enable the error in the same block, you can write `#pylint: enable=E1101` at the end of the block where you wish to surpress the `E1101` warnings.

Comment: http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html