# Unable to import 'users.signals'pylint(import-error)

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I am trying this for the first time and i got error in importing signals

from apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ChitchatConfig(AppConfig):
   name = 'chitchat'

   def ready(self):
       import users.signals
```

from signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import user_Profile


@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        user_Profile(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def save_profile(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    instance.user_Profile.save()
```

Comment: Is `signals.py` in a directory called `users`, which is at the same directory level as `apps.py`?  If so, delete your functions, then imports,  in `signals.py` to see which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has its own import statements, and it's known that pylint -- which is designed for standard python code -- can't interpret some import statements properly and might raise errors.

Here's how you should fix this:

1. Install this plugin: `pip install pylint-django`
2. Create a `pylintrc` file on the outermost layer of your project. Add `--load-plugins pylint_django` to this file. Save the file and reload your workspace.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31000713/12467282) and [package documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/).